# spring amqp dead letter queue does not work with transaction

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-dsl

How can I setup listener container when is channelTransacted(true) to throw message into dead letter queue when is something wrong instead of requeue? When I do not use channelTransacted, everything works fine and I can see the message in the dead letter queue.

```
@Bean(name = "amqpInboundEsignRequest")
public IntegrationFlow amqpInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, esignIAutoRequestQueue())
                    .acknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO)
                    .messageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter())
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .defaultRequeueRejected(false)
                    //.channelTransacted(true) // dead letter does not work
                    //.transactionManager(transactionManager) // dead letter does not work
    )
            .log("amqpInbound.start-process")
            .handle(p -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("Something wrong!");
            })
            .get();
}
```

**EDIT**

These are versions of dependencies.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.7.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.4.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

I would like to have transaction synchronized with the external transaction db (PlatformTransactionManager). When I set transactionManager(transactionManager) on listener container it always do requeue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using? I just tested `channelTransacted=true` with Spring Integration 5.0.2 and Spring AMQP 2.0.2, as well as Spring Integration 4.3.14 and Spring AMQP 1.7.6 and everything works as expected, the failed message went to the DLQ.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48914749Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48914749Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "foo")
                        .acknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO)
                        .messageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter())
                        .autoStartup(true)
                        .defaultRequeueRejected(false)
                        .channelTransacted(true) // dead letter does not work
        // .transactionManager(transactionManager) // dead letter does not work
        )
                .log("amqpInbound.start-process")
                .handle(p -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Something wrong!");
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("foo")
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "")
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "dlq")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue dlq() {
        return new Queue("dlq");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "dlq")
    public void dlq(Message in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

result:

> (Body:'[B@17793549(byte[8])' MessageProperties [headers={x-first-death-exchange=, x-death=[{reason=rejected, count=1, exchange=, time=Wed Feb 21 16:43:48 EST 2018, routing-keys=[foo], queue=foo}], x-first-death-reason=rejected, x-first-death-queue=foo}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=dlq, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=4, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-dOypXDkkQ5Hvw2W9cUIpzg, consumerQueue=dlq])

**EDIT**

Please be more precise in future; your question implied the same problem occurred regardless of whether a transaction manager was provided.

See [the second NOTE under **A note on Rollback of Received Messages**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#transaction-rollback). This is fixed in 2.0.

In 1.7.x, we had to retain the old behavior by default, for backwards compatibility. The [1.7.x documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.7.6.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#transaction-rollback) explains that you have to set the `alwaysRequeueWithTxManagerRollback` to `false` the get the new (consistent) behavior.

This is a listener container property so you will need to wire up a container and inject it into the inbound channel adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I updated my question.

Comment: Please be more precise in future; your question implied the same problem occurred regardless of whether a transaction manager was provided.

Comment: I apologize for the inaccurate information. Thank you very much. It is working perfectly now